# How can i find the complexity of this recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, recursion

Basically i'm having this recurrence relation which i don't know how to get the complexity of it by using the iterative method

$T(n) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $n=0$} \\
1, & \text{if $n=1$} \\
3T(n-1)+ 4T(n-2),  & \text{if $n >1$} 
\end{cases}$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such thing as the complexity of a recurrence relation. I think you want the *solution* of the recurrence relation, which may in turn measure the complexity of some algorithm or another. What's "the iterative method"?

Answer (score 0):

Solve: $x^2 - 3x - 4 = 0 \Rightarrow (x-4)(x+1) = 0 \Rightarrow x = 4, -1 \Rightarrow T_n = A\cdot 4^n + B\cdot (-1)^n$.

$T_0 = 0, T_1 = 1 \Rightarrow 0 = A+B, 1 = 4A-B \Rightarrow A = \dfrac{1}{5}, B = -\dfrac{1}{5} \Rightarrow T_n = \dfrac{4^n -(-1)^n}{5}$